Fantasy Drama Movie about a Girl Looking for her Father
I'm looking for a movie. The scenes I can remember (not in any particular order):

Abandoned white gazebo, table and chairs. Either in the middle or edge of a lake.on a dock and hasn't been used in years
Teen girl finds her dads (might be a journal) in a hut or cottage.
She finds another young girl still 9 ish in a cave. cloths are dirty and greyed with age
Has to open a door, once opened it looks like a white round library/ballroom.
this door might be standing by its self or set into a vine covered hill
Finding out she or the other girl was hit in the head with a rock (or knocked unconscious and thought dead. but not there when returned.
2 young girls maybe 9 years old playing near a lake wearing white dresses find a cave in the woods
Memory of mother (who died) laughing with father at the gazebo by the lake. mother had long wavy blonde hair
She is walking (away from camera) along a forested road as the ending credits start.
2 girls playing near lake in white dresses and mother warns them "not to play near the lake, they might ruin their dresses"

The other girl is her sister, but she won't remember that till after the door is open.
It was in color, English language and live action. probably was released between 70s and 90s, but no later then 98. might be older
She had to figure out, why the cave scared her and find the key for the door. The actor who (I believe) played her father, wore a tunic and vest. Also he had long dark hair. I can see him clearly in my minds eye but can not find him via Google. father part might be from something else
She was looking for her father, I think.
I think the door was white and I believe the key was her but she had to be ready/truly want to open the door. There was something near the door that told her how to open it. (in riddle, but not really a riddle) "to open the door, you have to want to open it" or "to open the door, you have to be ready, to open it" she would reply like "but i do want to open it" or "but i am ready" and no, not the labyrinth
It was perhaps fantasy drama.
What I remember of the cave is, after the main entryway it spit left and right, but if she went either way, she would came out the other one.
Not sure if this helps but when I watched it, it was on late night cable television, I don't remember the channel, sorry.
I don't remember what country it was from, could be UK. It's not Pippi Longstocking Adventure, The Secret Garden, Haunted (1995) or More Winners: The Journey.
